# How to i display information from a smart contract on my wordpress website

Tags: contract-design, contract-deployment

I want to display specific information from a smart contract on the main ether network on a wordpress website i can't seem to be able to do that, all tutorials only show test networks. the smart contract is already running on the ether network.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is to try and connect your webpage to something like Infura. (https://infura.io/). They have fantastic tutorials, this question is a bit broad to cover in a single answer to be  honest. But looking at Infura should get you started open up a new question if you have trouble with a specific part fo the process or alternatively clearly point us to where exactly you are in the set up process, it is very difficult to help with no details.